# jonthornton timepicker - disable second time after choosing first time

Tags: jquery, html, timepicker

As title said, how to disable previous time range after choosing the first time duration. Words can't describe my problem. So i provide some coding to clarify it more.

My html timepicker looks like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><b>Time (From)</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="time_picker" id="timefrom1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><b>Time (To)</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="time_picker" id="timeto1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Have Time (from) and Time (to) which is more like duration. Oh and first of all im using jonthornton timepicker. So my js timepicker script looks like this:

```
$('body').on('focus',".time_picker",function(){
    $(this).timepicker({
        'minTime': '1.00am',
        'timeFormat': 'H:i:s', 
        'stopScrollPropagation': 'true',
        'showOnFocus': 'true',
        'disableTextInput': 'true',
        'disableTouchKeyboard': 'true',
    });
});
```

My problem is that i want to disable the previous time range AFTER the Time (from) has been choosed. Which means that when focus on Time (to), i want to change the range for selection time is after that Time (From)

For example, if Time (from) time choosed is 04:00:00 (24 format) . Then when focus on Time (to) the range between 04:00:00, 03:00:00 and so on is disable. Only 04:00:00, 05:00:00 and continue is available.

Need assistance.

UPDATE: Apology for nonsense english. Let just say i want to avoid the user from picking the time that pass one day such as Time (From) = 04:00:00 and Time (To) = 02:00:00 for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `changeTime` on the **from** time and set the **to** time with `.timepicker('option', 'minTime', value)`

```js
$('#timefrom1, #timeto1').timepicker({
  'minTime': '1.00am',
  'timeFormat': 'H:i:s',
  'stopScrollPropagation': 'true',
  'showOnFocus': 'true',
  'disableTextInput': 'true',
  'disableTouchKeyboard': 'true',
});

$('#timefrom1').on('changeTime', function() {

  var values = $(this).val().split(':');
  if (values[1] == '00') {
    values[1] = '30';
  } else {
    values[0] = +values[0] + 1;
    values[1] = '00';
  }

  $('#timeto1').timepicker('option', 'minTime', values.join(':'));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><b>Time (From)</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="time_picker" id="timefrom1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><b>Time (To)</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="time_picker" id="timeto1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my holy god. You are genius. I didnt realize onChange would help on this thing. Also i am not familiar with split and join stuff. Thanks for make me learning about this. My problem solve thanks to you. This is what i need "onChange". Upvoted